# Eventlisteners for jqm side panel on multiple pages

Tags: panel, transition, event-listener, jquery-mobile

I am new to JQM and I'm using Phongeap with JQM for a new project. 
My javascript is in one single js file and I'm loading the views from multiple html files.

As the transitions of the siede panel are poor, when I change pages via `<a href="page2.html">` I tried to to use event listeners for the Menuitems.

```
    function setPanelListeners(){
    $('#menu_search').click(function() {
                            switchPageTo('search.html');
                            });
    $('#menu_schedule').click(function() {
                              switchPageTo('program.html');
                              });
    $('#menu_news').click(function() {
                              switchPageTo('news.html');
                              });
}
```

I call this function on the pagebeforeshoe event of each page. To fix the transitions to the way I need it, I use this function

```
    // Close Panel then change page
function switchPageTo(url){
    $('#menupanel').panel('close');
    setTimeout(function() {
               $.mobile.changePage( url, { transition: 'fade'} );
            },200);
}
```

So here is the Problem. It actually works fine on the first page. But on the second page the Menuitems won't work, I guess the event listers are not listening for the new panel, because in the html the panel is loaded twice! And the Event listeners only listen for the first panel (from the first page) which is not displayed on the second page.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you adding panel dynamically on the second page? In JQM 1.3 you have to add panel separately to each page, although this restriction will be removed in future versions.

Use event delegation for dynamic panels:

```
$(document).on('click' ,'#menu_search' function() {
        switchPageTo('search.html')
   });
```